# How do I migrate a Task List from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, migration

I'm looking for a way to migrate a SharePoint 2007 task list to SharePoint 2010 and preserve all the fields (including Description, which is typically not shown in columns).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried exporting from 2007 to Access or Excel then importing into the 2010?

Comment: Good suggestion! Did it solve your problem @Ryan ?